# Reading a table using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing difficulties when trying to read the following table using selenium.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxyRM.png)

The locator is as below

`@FindBy(css = "table.table-bordered.table-striped")
 private WebElement storesTable;`

`List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.tagName("/tbody/tr"));`

The count of rows is 0 when the code is run. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is: you are giving invalid `TagName` as `"/tbody/tr"` plus you need to change you `storesTable` as below because `tr` is present under `tbody` :

```
@FindBy(css = "table.table-bordered.table-striped > tbody")
private WebElement storesTable;
```

and after changing your tagName:

```
List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Comment: Hi @kushal, Thanks for your reply. This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You are providing xpath in place of tagName.

If you want to use tagname below is the statement

```
List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Or else if you want to use xpath below is the statement.

```
List<WebElement> storeRows = storesTable.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr"));
```

Comment: Hi Akarsh, Thanks for you reply. Will try your solution as well